# How to stay on same page after click "submit" button, and keep the date I entered in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

1. After clicking "submit", stay on this page.
2. Input data, like "computer number" and "profit", stay inside those blank square.
3. A word "Submitted", appear in the center of this page.

The following is my code,
Please help, thank you!

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

  <body>

  <form name="my form" 
onsubmit="return validateForm()">
   
    Computer Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Computer" required><br>
  
<p>How much is your profit?                                 

<input id="id1" name = "id1" required>
  <button  type = "button" onclick="myFunction()">Check My Answer</button> 
    <button type="button" id="btn1" onclick="Solution()" style="display:none;">Solution</button>
    </p>

<p id="Q1"></p>

<script>
var errosCount = 0;
  function myFunction() {
    var x, text;
    x = document.getElementById("id1").value;
   
    if (isNaN(x) || x != 100) {
        text = "Incorrect"; document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";errosCount++;
    } else {
        text = "Correct"; document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "green";
    }
    document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = text;
         if(errosCount === 3){
        errosCount = 0;
        document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = '';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = 'none';        
      } 
}
function Solution(){
  text = "(P - w) * q<sub>o</sub> - I = (53 - 43) * 30 - 200 = 100";  document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = text;
}      
</script>
 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  
</form>
  
  <script>
function validateForm() {
    var q = document.forms["my form"]["Computer"].value;
    if (q == "") {
        alert("Computer Number is Missing!");
        return false;}
  var w = document.forms["my form"]["id1"].value;
    if (w != "100") {
        alert("Question 1 is Incorrect!");
        return false;}
  
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: form is to be submit by ajax and on success , submitted message should come . So where is ajax logic

Comment: Can you provide an example? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `validateForm()` I have added `else` logic which is used for displaying the submitted message and stops the form from being redirected.

Things to do.

Add logic according to your requirement how to submit the form through XMLHttpRequest way. For more see  [Sending forms through JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="my form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

    Computer Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Computer" required><br>

    <p>How much is your profit?

      <input id="id1" name="id1" required>
      <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check My Answer</button>
      <button type="button" id="btn1" onclick="Solution()" style="display:none;">Solution</button>
    </p>

    <p id="Q1"></p>

    <script>
      var errosCount = 0;

      function myFunction() {
        var x, text;
        x = document.getElementById("id1").value;

        if (isNaN(x) || x != 100) {
          text = "Incorrect";
          document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";
          errosCount++;
        } else {
          text = "Correct";
          document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "green";
        }
        document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = text;
        if (errosCount === 3) {
          errosCount = 0;
          document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = '';
        } else {
          document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      function Solution() {
        text = "(P - w) * q<sub>o</sub> - I = (53 - 43) * 30 - 200 = 100";
        document.getElementById("Q1").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("Q1").innerHTML = text;
      }
    </script>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <span id="success"></span>

  </form>

  <script>
    function validateForm() {
      var q = document.forms["my form"]["Computer"].value;
      if (q == "") {
        alert("Computer Number is Missing!");
        return false;
      }
      var w = document.forms["my form"]["id1"].value;
      if (w != "100") {
        alert("Question 1 is Incorrect!");
        return false;
      } else {
        /* ajax logic here and on success message this message is followed*/
        document.getElementById('success').innerHTML = "<b>Submitted</b>"
        return false; /*stops the form from being submitted normal way*/
      }

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```